# svn commit failed, but old revision in repo was changed with my edit

Tags: svn, commit

I made a minor change to a file we're using, and was going to commit my edit.

```
$ svn commit -m "comment"
Sending        pom.xml
svn: E160042: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160042: File or directory 'pom.xml' is out of date; try updating
svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating
```

AFAIK, nothing should have changed in the repo now, right?
Apparently someone had made a change and I had forgotten to update my working copy before editing the file, I update.

```
$ svn update
Updating '.':
U    another.unrelated.file
G    pom.xml
Updated to revision 11943.
```

As expected, our changes was merged (into my working copy, right?), so I check the status.

```
$ svn status
```

No change? Why? Shouldn't the merged working copy of *pom.xml* be marked as modified?
I run `svn info` to see what's been going on.

```
$ svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: working/dir
URL: https://not.relevant
Repository Root: https://not.relevant
Repository UUID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Revision: 11943
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: otherguy
Last Changed Rev: 11856
Last Changed Date: 2012-01-04 16:12:42 +0100 (Wed, 04 Jan 2012)
```

Shouldn't "Last Changed" be my change instead of the one by *otherguy* 8 days ago? So I cat the repo file to see what's ACTUALLY there.

```
svn cat https://company.com/repo/path/to/pom.xml | less
```

And it shows the merged version of the file! (With the changes made by both me and otherguy).

What has happened here? Did svn change an existing revision of a file with my change without updating any metadata? Is that even possible?

Comment: Turns out otherguy had made the EXACT same changes as me, so my commit was never made (or needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your working copy is still out of date.

The redbook says:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html

> If your working copy is out of date (or you have local modifications)
>   and you want to see the HEAD revision of a file in your working copy,
>   svn cat -r HEAD FILENAME will automatically fetch the HEAD revision of
>   the specified path:

Was your local pom.xml actually different from the one fetched from the repo?

Comment: My working copy is definitely up to date. There is of course the slight possibility of my change already existing in HEAD (added by otherguy), so that after the update, my change would be redundant. That would give the behaviour described, wouldn't it?

Comment: That would be a logically explanation. For sure we have to go through the svn client source code for svn status and svn cat. Something tells me I don't have time for that :-)

Comment: Turns out that was the case too! Otherguy had changed the exact same thing in his last commit, which made mine totally redundant, and therefore no commit was needed.